# Rotation operator from angular momentum or spin operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

My instructor on quantum physics just stated that the total angular momentum operator, $\hat{J}$, can be expressed as $\hat{J}=\hat{L}+\hat{S}$, where $\hat{L}$ is angular momentum operator corresponding to the movement of the particle, and $\hat{S}$ is the angular momentum operator corresponding to the spin of the particle.

Suddenly, he said that the unitary operator for a rotation of an angle $\theta$ around the axis $\mathbb{n}$, is given by
$$
U_R(\theta) = \exp \left( -i\dfrac{\theta}{\hbar} \mathbb{n}\cdot(\hat{L}+\hat{S}) \right)\ .
$$

Where does this last statement come from?

Comment: How do you mean "suddenly"? Have you not learned that rotation operators are exponentials of the hermitian angular momentum operator, an *i* and an angle? See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Angular_momentum_as_the_generator_of_rotations).

Comment: Related links that might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_operator_(quantum_mechanics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix